# How can I get my React App to correctly send page title in link previews? Using NGINX as proxy

Tags: reactjs, nginx, hyperlink, react-router, metadata

so I've got a React app being served by Nginx and it uses an API server backend to which the NGINX server forwards requests, which is consumed by the React App. The react app uses the React Router package for routing.

Most of the react app is pretty simple, when you go to a specific page, it mounts a React Component which fetches some data from the API Server, and then updates itself to display that data. In doing so, it also updates the Document Title and other metadata related to the data that was fetched.

The react app is just a basic Create-React-App scaffolded application and the NGINX config is just pointing and the default index.html (which in turn loads the javascript chunks etc, standard React infrastructure).

I have a problem now where the app generally works well but if you copy a link from the app and paste it to someone, it will always show the base title of the application, and indeed if you preview the HTML source of any page on the webapp, it will always show the base title.

Here is an example (although SO doesn't do metadata link previews afaik):

https://bugwalker.io/bugs/92

My guess is that the requests that fetch metadata for a link, or fetch source page, don't have Javascript enabled and as a result it never mounts the react components and never gets to update the title etc.

Is there a way to fetch the metadata to populate the title and other metadata even when javascript is disabled? Or is there something else going on that I am completely missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For this you need react helmet: https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet. On each page of your React application you should specify the title like so:

```
<Helmet>
  <title>Some Page</title>
</Helmet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately I already tried that without luck. One of my pages sets the title with Helmet but when you link to it it still comes up with base title :(

Comment: @coryn sounds like you have <title> tag in index.html. Remove this from index.html and specify all titles using react-helmet on every page of application.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help, without a title in the index.html it just doesn't return a title at all. I think it doesn't even load my react app, it just returns the index.html source :(

Comment: Yes that's right. To preview links with all meta data you need server-side rendering. Take a look at next.js, gatsby etc.